# Date wise average of joined records from a table

Tags: mysql

**Structure**

```
Table: HOUSEHOLD (id, form_date)

TABLE: HOUSEHOLD_MEMBERS (id, HOUSEHOLD_ID, MEMBER_NAME, ... )
```

e.g. for a given household there maybe 5, 6, 8, 10 household members in HOUSEHOLD_MEMBERS table.

**What I am trying**

Average number of household members on a given date.

Output should be like:

```
[DATE, AVERAGE]

[2016-03-01, 5.4]
[2016-03-02, 4.9]
[2016-03-03, 6.7]
```

**What I've done so far**

```
SELECT 
DATE(HOUSEHOLD.form_date) AS DATE_ONLY,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HOUSEHOLD_MEMBERS WHERE HOUSEHOLD.id = HOUSEHOLD_MEMBERS.HOUSEHOLD_ID) AS COUNT

FROM
DATA
GROUP BY DATE_ONLY
```

Its far from near from the result I am expecting, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A result set minus a data set is next to useless.

Comment: Can you explain a bit, what you meant?

Comment: Please post your related table structures (`create table code`) and some sample input output.@Ayub

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(h.form_date) AS DATE,
    COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT h.id) AS AVERAGE
FROM
    HOUSEHOLD h INNER JOIN HOUSEHOLD_MEMBERS hm ON h.id = hm.HOUSEHOLD_ID
GROUP BY DATE;
```

Comment: Also execution time of your query is more optimum 0.135s as compared to 0.499s

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT HDATE, AVG(cnt)
FROM (
  SELECT DATE(H.FORM_DATE) AS HDATE, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM HOUSEHOLD_MEMBER AS HM
  INNER JOIN HOUSEHOLD AS H ON HM.HOUSEHOLD_ID = H.ID
  GROUP BY DATE(H.FORM_DATE), H.ID) AS t
GROUP BY HDATE
```

The inner query returns the count of members per household, per date. The outer query returns the average number per date.

Comment: GROUP BY DATE(H.FORM_DATE), H.ID), here i think GROUP BY DATE(H.FORM_DATE) is not necessary, also if we just group by H.ID the results are same

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql

```
select from_date,AVG(HOUSEHOLD_ID) from HOUSEHOLD as h join HOUSEHOLD_MEMBERS as hm
on hm.HOUSEHOLD_ID=h.id GROUP BY from_date
```